Programatically add or remove Hangfire Server and Queues
We have a multi-tenant asp.net mvc (framework, not core) app in which we create Hangfire servers and queues by tenenant at app startup. When we have a new tenant sign up or one leave, we'd like to add or remove their servers/queues without having to restart the app. Is there anyway to do this for .net framework? I've seen this question about how to do it in .net core.

Which version of HangFire
And a suggestion, Using directly database sometimes better !

Why didn't you try to add it as service and use AddTransient or AddScoped(base on your need) and let .Net Framework handle services life cycle for ya?
for example
builder.Services.AddScoped<ILogger>();

or
builder.Services.AddTransient<ILogger>();

wish this help you
